# Get current action in jsp - struts2

Tags: java, facebook, jsp, struts2

the thing is I'd like to get the current url in a jsp page, but not showing the .jsp page but the action name. For example:

I have the action http://www.mypage.com/Index, which displays the page http://www.mypage.com/pages/index.jsp. Is there any way I could obtain the first Url in a jsp file? What I have always returns the path to the jsp, but what I want is the action name. What I have is:

```
<%=  (request.getServletPath()) %>
```

and

```
${pageContext.request.requestURL}?${pageContext.request.queryString} //to get the id attached
```

I want this for a simple facebook share button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="${pageContext.request.requestURL}?${pageContext.request.queryString}" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<s:url>` tag for that.

```
<s:url forceAddSchemeHostAndPort="true" includeParams="all"/>
```

The `forceAddSchemeHostAndPort` attribute setted to `true` will add your host name with port and `includeParams` setted to `all` will include all parameters to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just want the action name with JSTL you can use

```
${request.context['struts.actionMapping'].name}
```